# Schedule workflow or email notification

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, designer-workflow, schedule

Just wondering, is there a way to schedule (e.g. 1st day of each Month) a workflow or send email notification for a list, without using powershell or C# code.

Comment: Workflows aren't meant to be timer jobs. That's what timer jobs are for. So there's not a sensible way to achieve this with an OOTB workflow. The only option that comes to mind is having a loop check the date constantly and relying on SP to rate-limit it by default (which it does, but if you're looking for month-long gaps there's still going to be a lot of unnecessary calls going on).

Comment: For this purpose you can use 3rd party solutions, for example http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/